# Get android device info via usb

Tags: android, usb

I've a question, I can't find what I'm looking for so I decided to ask my question here.

I want to see on my computer what android device is connected (without .
Is this even possible?

And on what way?

Thx,

Comment: Have you tried android debug bridge?http://developer.android.com/tools/help/adb.html

Comment: I'm sorry, thats not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You should really try to do it with ADB.

Install the Android SDK (ADB will come with it)

After that, get the android version of a plugged device is quite simple:

1. Plug the device in your USB.
2. Open the terminal (or cmd.exe if you are using Windows)
3. Run the command: `adb shell getprop ro.build.version.release`

Hope it helps.